# Can someone please assist with this MSDN code?

Tags: c#

Still new to C#, trying my hardest to figure things out, but Ive already found bugs in some MSDN code. Today, I tried the example code at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but just can't get it to work.

My question is, where exactly do I specify the directory path?

I tried inserting `string path = "c:\\test";` after

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
```

but it did not work.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Are you calling your program with command line arguments? args comes from the command line

Comment: Please note that posting the appropriate content from a site is preferred to just linking to it (include the link also though!) In this case, the example is so large and easy to access that its an "edge" case for me. Just something to be aware of. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3):

The linked sample is taking advantage of **command line arguments** to get its input (thats what the `args` array is populated with). This means that you run the program like this:

> MySampleApp.exe "C:\Test"

Setting the `path` variable does nothing, since that variable is created and scoped to the foreach in the very next line. If anything, you would need to reassign the `args` variable.

Since you are likely new to C#, a quick note on scoping. A "scope" is an area where a variable lives. Whenever you create a variable, it is accessible to its scope and any below it. When the compiler looks up a variable, it picks the *deepest* match.

Scopes are made by `{}`, so

```
void Main(string[] args)
{  //New scope here (function scope)
   string path = "C:\Test"; //Creates variable at function scope

   foreach (string path in args) //Declare a new variable called path, the 
                                 //foreach semantic scopes it to the next block
   {                             
      ... //Any reference to "path" here will reference the foreach 
          //iteration variable, NOT the function scope variable
   }
```

Hopefully that helps explain why your code didn't do what you thought it would!

Comment: Technically, you don't have to quote the path `C:\Test` since there are no embedded spaces. But that is quite unlikely in anything but this most contrived of examples, so I think it makes for a better sample.

Comment: @CodyGray Not a problem. Putting the quotes is definitely better practice!